# C++ trying to create a queue of 2d points (arrays)

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

I am trying to create a queue of 2d points, like this:

```cpp
queue<int[2]> q;
```

this compiles, however, after doing:

```cpp
q.push({0,0});
```

I get an compile error, saying that my call to `push` is ambiguous. Not sure how to fix this. Please help.

I'm not sure if this is a good way to represent 2d points on a plane, but it seems to me to be the most lightweight.

Comment: Use `std::array` instead

Comment: Just make a struct (not int[2], and not std::pair) with an x and y value. It is always a good idea to make datatypes that represent a concept. e.g. `struct point_2d { int x; int y; };` (that way you cannot accidentaly pass a int[2] to function intended to work on points) then make a std::queue, or std::vector out of those.

Comment: @PepijnKramer yeah, a struct fixes it. it does seem like a good idea here. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pair to represent your points.

```
queue<pair<int,int>>q;
q.push({0,0});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a structure for the 2D points:

```
struct Point2D {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

And you can create a `std::vector` instead of `std::queue`.

```
std::vector<Point2D> q {{ {1, 2}, {9, 3}, ... }};
```

And you can normally:

```
q.push_back({0, 0});
```

EDIT:
You can also create a vector of `int[2]` instead of `Point2D` and do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a struct to hold your point coordinates. It's actually a good idea to have a representation for such entity regardless of your current problem.

The answer below is a more general one regarding arrays in c++, and does not require a custom struct:

In c++ it's usually recomended to use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of such small fixed size c style arrays (and [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for dynamic size ones).

**Code example:**

```
#include <queue>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::queue<std::array<int,2>> q;
    q.push({ 0,0 });
    return 0;
}
```

**A side note:** better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

Array are just pointers. Raw C arrays cannot be stored in container.

**Solution 1**: Use type of stored element as int*

```
std::queue<int*> q1;
int s1[2]{0,0};
q1.push(s1);
```

**Solution 2**: Use other container like std::array or std::vector

```
std::queue<std::array<int,2>> q;
q.push({0,0});
```

Comment: storing the array pointers in the queue is unwise unless the arrays are guaranteed to have longer lifetimes that the queue

Comment: Agree! Solutions are just samples of possible ways to solve it. Depending on the use case, use heap or stack, but this is outside the scope of this question.